# How to install rigorously KDE Plasma on Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: system-installation, kde, plasma

I'm trying to install KDE plasma on Ubuntu 16.10, but I didn't find out how to do it. Could anyone be able to describe to me rigorously how to do it with the terminal. I thought this [website](http://www.tecmint.com/install-kde-plasma-5-in-linux/) was great, but I don't have Kubuntu.

```
jeremie@jeremie-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
kubuntu-desktop is already the newest version (1.344).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  kde-l10n-engb
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up linux-image-4.8.0-26-generic (4.8.0-26.28) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
initrd.img(/boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-26-generic
) points to /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-26-generic
 (/boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-26-generic) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.8.0-26-generic.postinst line 491.
vmlinuz(/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-26-generic
) points to /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-26-generic
 (/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-26-generic) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.8.0-26-generic.postinst line 491.
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.8.0-26-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-26-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.8.0-26-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-26-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.8.0-26-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-26-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-26-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.8.0-26-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-26-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.8.0-26-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-26-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.8.0-26-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-26-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/vboxadd 4.8.0-26-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-26-generic
run-parts: failed to exec /etc/kernel/postinst.d/vboxadd: Exec format error
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/vboxadd exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.8.0-26-generic.postinst line 1052.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.8.0-26-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-4.8.0-26-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.8.0-26-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-4.8.0-26-generic:
 linux-image-extra-4.8.0-26-generic depends on linux-image-4.8.0-26-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.8.0-26-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.8.0-26-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 4.8.0.26.35); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not confiNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                    No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                            gured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.8.0-26-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.8.0-26-generic
 linux-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop` doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I was doing that command.

Comment: What errors did it give?

Comment: It was almost completed, but I've got the error `E: sub-process /user/bin/dpkg return an error code (1)`. What does it mean according to you?

Comment: It's impossible to tell from just that line. Please post the entire output in your main question. Thanks!

Comment: It seems that the error comes from the DPKG. Do I have to make a purge or something like that?

Comment: Do you have enough disk space in your `/boot` partition? Can you add the output of the `df -h /boot` command?

Comment: Also, I ran into [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/hundredpapercuts/+bug/1622499) when I was trying to install Kubuntu Desktop on my laptop, which affects 16.04/16.10. Certainly different from yours, based on output, but you should keep it in mind.

Comment: How could we add the output of the `df -h /boot` command? Sorry, I'm learning this language actually with Cisco. With that command I got `Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        30G   10G   19G  36% /`

Comment: Does this problem still exists? The problem is not about Kubuntu or Plasma but the linux kernel. Please do a `sudo apt-get update && apt-get -f install` and give us the output if the error still exists.